# English language trick in mathematics problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

i would like to consider following problem,which mostly became trick because of hidden information what is actually asked,when i   was preparing  for GRE questions ,there was  asked such kind of question,for example like this

suppose that Bob has income  $A$,where $A$ is some number,Bob's another  additional income $B$ is defined as  let say $1450$ plus  $15$%  that exceeds $1500$, suppose that Bob's  income $A$ is $3000$,find Bob's income $B$,actually what  a most people(non native speakers) will do  is $1450+15/100* 3000$,but  trick  is that is ask somehow  difference between $(3000-1500)$,or income $B$ would be

$1450+15/100*(3000-1500)$

how it could be so that  there is so hidden information,or asked non clearly exactly from which i could take  $15$ %?please help me

Comment: There is no "hidden information" in the wording, but some necessary information is blurred by the nonsensical phrase "15% that exceeds 1500".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

15% that exceeds 1500: We won't that 15% of 3000, We would take 15% of what is left after consuming or taking out 1500, that is we have to take 15% of what is more than 1500.